# Applying jQuery toggle function to each table

Tags: jquery, html

I have three html tables on a webpage that are generated using a tornado framework.  When a user clicks on a table, I would like all rows of this table to toggle hidden / shown, except for the first and last rows of this table.  I am trying to use jQuery's each and toggle to accomplish this.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/kauk975e/

```
$(".hidesomerows").each(function() {
  $(function(){
    $(function() {
      $('table').click(function() {
        console.log('click registered');
        $(this).parent().find("tr").not(":last").not(":first").toggle();
        console.log('why you no work?');
      });
    });
  });
});
```

When I click on the first table, it prints my two debug message to the console once for each table displayed, but doesn't hide the rows.  Nothing happens when I click on the second or third table.  What am I missing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `.parent()`, as event handler is attached with `TABLE` element. the current element context `this` will refer it. So directly use `.find()` to target the `TR`s

```
$('table.hidesomerows').click(function() {
  $(this).find("tr").not(":last").not(":first").toggle();
});
```

```js
$('table.hidesomerows').click(function() {
  $(this).find("tr").not(":last").not(":first").toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table hidesomerows">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>foo</th>
      <th>bar</th>
      <th>x</th>
      <th>y</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> alpha </td>
      <td> alpha </td>
      <td>-20.0</td>
      <td>20.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>beta</td>
      <td>beta</td>
      <td>124.390625</td>
      <td>-20.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>gamma</td>
      <td>gamma</td>
      <td>124.390625</td>
      <td>-20.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>total</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> 0 </td>
      <td> -20 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table class="table hidesomerows">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>foo</th>
      <th>bar</th>
      <th>x</th>
      <th>y</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> alpha </td>
      <td> alpha </td>
      <td>-20.0</td>
      <td>20.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>beta</td>
      <td>beta</td>
      <td>124.390625</td>
      <td>-20.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>gamma</td>
      <td>gamma</td>
      <td>124.390625</td>
      <td>-20.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>total</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> 0 </td>
      <td> -20 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<table class="table hidesomerows">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>foo</th>
      <th>bar</th>
      <th>x</th>
      <th>y</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> alpha </td>
      <td> alpha </td>
      <td>-20.0</td>
      <td>20.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>beta</td>
      <td>beta</td>
      <td>124.390625</td>
      <td>-20.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>gamma</td>
      <td>gamma</td>
      <td>124.390625</td>
      <td>-20.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>total</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> 0 </td>
      <td> -20 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked.  Thank you!  Will select after the 8 min mark